# Swift: add forward/backward 15 seconds buttons on lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have `AVAudioPlayer`. And I want to add 15 seconds rewind buttons on lock screen like on this image:

[image]

But I have this result like on this image:

[image]

My code:

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    ...

    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)
    restorePlayerCurrentTime()
}

override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let event = event else {
            print("no event\n")
            return
        }
        guard event.type == UIEventType.remoteControl else {
            print("received other event type\n")
            return
        }
        
        switch event.subtype {
        
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlBeginSeekingBackward:
            audioPlayer.play()
        
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlBeginSeekingForward:
            audioPlayer.pause()
        
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPlay:
            print("received remote play\n")
            audioPlayer.play()
        case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlPause:
            print("received remote pause\n")
            audioPlayer.pause()
        
        /*case UIEventSubtype.remoteControlTogglePlayPause:
            print("received toggle\n")*/
            
        default:
            print("received \(event.subtype) which we did not process\n")
        }
    }
```

How to fix it?

Play and stop buttons works fine but rewind doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this

```
import MediaPlayer

func setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()  {
   
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    
commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event in
    print("You Pressed skipForward")
    return .success
}

commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.addTarget { [weak self] event in
    print("You Pressed skipBackward")
    return .success
}

}
```

this will get you the skip buttons.

call it from

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()
}
```

Comment: I add it to my code and add breakpoint in this function. But this function not called. Why?

Comment: Import MediaPlayer and call the function from viewDidLoad

Comment: Works fine. But I have some problems. 1. On lock screen I see buttons icon rewind to +10 or -10. How to change it to 15? 2. I also add `changePlaybackPositionCommand` but when I click in buttons rewind the track is rewind fine. But slider not change position

Comment: I solved first question. But not solved 2.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your quesiton 2;

you need to update MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime to match CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() ), the best place to update this value would be to add an observer forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus" and update on .waitingToPlaySpecifieldRate / .paused and .playing

create a global dictionary called nowPlayingInfo
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter/1615903-nowplayinginfo

Example:

```
    nowPlayingInfo = nil
    
    nowPlayingInfo = [String: Any]()
    
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = data[0].currentTrackTitle
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = data[0].currentArtist
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle] = data[0].currentAlbumName
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] =  NSNumber(value: 1)
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] =  CMTimeGetSeconds((player!.currentItem?.asset.duration)!)
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() )
    let image = data[0].currentArtwork
    self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
        return image
    })
  
    
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo
```

In timeControlStatus oberver update the nowPlayingInfo global dictionary's  `self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() )

you also need to update MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate to 0 prior to seek (15 secs) and then set this value back to 1 after seeking has completed.

example;

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        
        guard context == &playerItemContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
            return
        }
        
        if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" {

            let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber
                // Switch over status value
                switch statusNumber {
                case 0:
                        //print("paused")
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] =  NSNumber(value: 0)
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() )
                        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo
                case 1:
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] =  NSNumber(value: 0)
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() )
                        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo
                case 2:
                        //print("playing")
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyDefaultPlaybackRate] =  NSNumber(value: 1)
                        self.nowPlayingInfo?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime() )
                        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = self.nowPlayingInfo
    
                        }
                default:
                        fatalError() //this is never called in this scenario
                }
        }

    }
```